# Simple Navigation Drawer

Tags: android

https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer#java

When I create the menu resource and input the code I get a error saying cannot resolve symbol. This is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="@string/import" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="@string/gallery" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
        android:title="@string/slideshow" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        android:title="@string/tools" />
</group>
</menu>
```

Comment: Is that back quote at the end of </menu> in your actual code or was that in error when asking the question?

Comment: sorry thats not in my code

Comment: Are you certain you have imported all the view components correctly into your class file?